# RadComboBox on OnClientItemChecked get sequence

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, telerik, radcombobox

I actually want to achieve in a multi select checkbox to have a sequence. When i access OnClientItemChecked 
on RadComboBox i get alert which is working here is the HTML code below.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox RenderMode="Lightweight" OnClientItemChecked="OnClientItemChecked" ID="cbo_Tag" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true" EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="true" Skin="MetroTouch" CssClass="form-control" Width="100%" />
```

Here is the code for javascript function below

```
function OnClientItemChecked(sender, eventArgs) {
        var item = eventArgs.get_item();
        console.log(item)
        console.log(sender)
        console.log(eventArgs)
        alert("Checked");
    }
```

i need to access by sequence when i select in checkbox sequentially one by one it i need to sequence the checkbox in an array with their value. If i use Checkbox All then their sequence should be from top to bottom how can i achieve so.Here is a image e.g.
[image: Sequence to add in array]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var checkItems = []

    function OnClientItemChecked(sender, eventArgs) {

        var checkItems = eventArgs.get_checkedItems();

    }
</script>
```

Whenever you click on a unchecked checkbox the checkBox id will be added to the `checkBoxIds` array.

Comment: thanks if i check all how do i get below items .. ?

Comment: I have edited my answer by using the `get_checkedItems()`. The following page is the documentation about the RadComboBox object: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/client-side-programming/objects/radcombobox-object

Comment: eventArgs.get_checkedItems is not a function

Comment: Actually i require check all to get values as well. I searched and used this OnClientCheckAllChecked as it only uses true false approach not get the values.